# Will a file be created if the directory doesnt exist?

Tags: java

Well my question is that if say I'm making a file like so

```
File f = new File("THE_Folder/me.txt");
```

But the folder "THE_Folder" doesnt exist, will the file still be created in the end when I'm saving the file? Will it create "THE_Folder" and the "me.txt"?

Comment: What happens when you tried? Not my down-vote, by the way.

Comment: -1: This question does not show any research effort.  See [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Did you ever try it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't. But there's a handy [createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) and [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) method for that.

More specifically, use `mkdirs()` to create the directories, but you'll want to call [getParentFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29) first because you don't want to create a directory called me.txt.

Then you can call the `createNewFile()` method to finally create your new file.

As EJP explained, it's not necessary to call `createNewFile()` since `FileOutputStream` and `FileWriter` will create the new file for you.

Comment: No there isn't. `File.createNewFile()` behaves the same way. It won't create missing intermediate directories.

Comment: Did you try this for a non-existent directory?

Comment: Oops, I just now did, and I corrected my answer.

Comment: You don't need to call `createNewFile().` Using the `File` in a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter`, as the OP is clearly going to do 'when saving the file', will create the file.

Comment: @EJP Good point. It seemed as if the OP was already aware of that, which is why I didn't mention it at the time.

Answer (score 2):

`File` does NOT create a file/folder, it merely opens a file, unless you call the method `createNewFile()`, which will create a file (not a folder) with the specified name. So, no, it won't

Comment: No 'unless' about it. `File.createNewFile()` doesn't create directories.

Comment: my bad. I didn't read the word 'folder' in the question. answer corrected :-)

Comment: You're still wrong. It doesn't 'open a file'. It just creates a `File` object in memory. It doesn't do anything to the file system whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `File` object in and of itself will never create a file or directory. You can call

```
File f2 = f.getParentFile();
if (f2 != null) f2.mkdirs();
```

to create the necessary directories if they don't exist. (You don't need the `null` check if you're sure that `f` specifies a parent directory, existing or otherwise.) After that, you can call

```
f.createNewFile();
```

to create the file itself. Note that if you try creating the file before creating the directories, you will get an `IOException`.

Comment: `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()` actually.